# SQL Dump is not creating tables

Tags: mysql, export

I created a good sized DB in MySQl on Windows tonight.  I need to export this data to a SQL file and I'd like to load a copy of it on another machine using this file.  When I use

```
mysql.exe  -u user -p foo < bar.sql
```

It act likes it's importing the data, by that I mean it takes a while.  Then I go and select my db, and show tables, nothing.  I exported my data from MySQL workbench 6.1.

edit:
I've also verified the data is in fact in the SQL file from the export.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mysqldump, it works like a charm.

```
mysqldump.exe -u user -p foo > dump.sql
```

and than you can import it in another machine

Comment: perfect, thanks!  Apparently I'm waiting 7 minutes to approve the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Important note:

```
shell> mysql -ptest
shell> mysql -p test
```

The first command instructs MySQL to use a password value of `test`, but specifies no default database. The second instructs MySQL to prompt for the password value and to use `test` as the default database. So double check how you invoke the command and its parameters.

Also for exporting data into `*.sql` file it is better to use `mysqldump.exe` utility. Read more [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
mysqldump -d -u username_user -p username_dbname > file.sql
```

Where `username_dbname` is the name of your database, and `file.sql` is the name of the file you would like to write the table structure to. It will prompt you for a password (-p) and this is required. Normally, `mysqldump` gives you the entire database, with the `-d` option, you tell it to not include the data, but just the table structure.

https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/180